# Retrieving Multiple lines From the property file for a single key

Tags: key, key-value, properties-file

In a property file I want to retrieve multiple lines for a single key value.

```
message: this is a message body
ja
adf
```

But only where the message is a key.
I want to be able to retrieve multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

It treats every next line will be treated as a new key.

Comment: You can do it with message2 = c = a string with a continuation line \
        continuation line \
        123

Comment: you need to append \ when there is line continuation. I find it [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-read-and-write-a-properties-file.html)